# Replace whole string with stars

Tags: php, replace

I need a solution to replace whole string with stars in PHP, for example there are strings like:

> test
>
> test123
>
> test1234

And depends on string length, it will replace string with the stars like:

`test` has 4 characters in length so it will be replaced with 4 stars `****`.

`test123` has 7 characters in length so it will be replaced with 7 stars `*******`. And so on...

Is there any good solution for that?

Comment: I really hope you are not utilizing simple masking to hide sensitive data (such as passwords). This method is extremely unsecured.

Comment: @PenguinCoder Well, I'm using it to hide some special codes. But may I know why are you calling this method extremely unsecured?

Comment: It would mean your methods of storing sensitive data are insecure, not particularly the masking itself. IE, if you're storing passwords (or other sensitive data) in plaintext anywhere, then its just a matter of time before someone gets their hands on your 'secured' data.

Comment: Well, its not really sensitive data, as its only a safebox code password in the game, but user will have to login on his account in order to see that stars password. So I guess its okay?

Comment: *So I guess its okay?* - What constitutes acceptable risk is completely up to you (or your supervisor if such is a work project) to determine. My comment was to bring attention to the method, and perhaps help you think of a better or more secure solution if my statement was indeed the case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$string = str_repeat('*', strlen($string));
```

Simply make a new string, consisting of all stars, with length equal to the original.