# Is it possible to replace a text with SOME stars?

Tags: php

I have a 16 digit text which contains ONLY numbers. I have a PHP variable, example: $example['example']
I want this variable to make like only the first 6 digit and the last 4 digit to be visible, the others will be replaced with a star.

**SOLVED** with https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ZPF.png

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Have you tried something?

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Thank you for your answer. I think it would possible with some scripts, but I only can understand PHP, HTML.

Comment: You can check following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437865/replace-whole-string-with-stars

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Yes, but I need to only change the characters from the 7th to the 12th to a star, not all the 16 numbers.

Comment: $var = "1234567890987654";
$var = substr_replace($var, "******", 0, 6);
$var = substr_replace($var, "****", 12, 15);

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour Thank you, I will check it now.

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour Your code is working, but very strange. I think you misunderstanded my comments above there. I want the stars from the 7th number to the 12th number. Not the first 6 number and the last 4 number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using str_replace function make to easy

```php
$example="1234567890123456";
$replace=str_replace(substr($example,6,6),str_repeat('*',6),$example);
echo "$replace";
```